# Converting 16-bit integer to 8-bit integer?

Tags: arithmetic

I found a question that asks for a method to copy a 16-bit sign and magnitude integer to an 8-bit sign and magnitude integer. Is that even possible? Could someone please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 8-bit integer where the first bit is reserved for sign can encode up to $2^7$ different objects. We would assume that we would encode all the integers from 0 to 127 with them. More importantly, if we chose say 500 different integers, one cannot encode all of them with 8 bits and preserve all the information.

With 15 bits, one can encode up to $2^{15}$ different things.

Instead of belaboring that, consider instead the alternative: one can store 16 bit integers into 8 bit integers. So take the maximum value storeable in a 16 bit integer and 'condense' it into an 8 bit integer. If we then take the 8 bit integer to be the latter half of a 16 bit integer, we can count higher until we hit a limit - another 'maximum storeable value' in a 16 bit integer. Clearly, these two 'maximum storeable values' must be equal!

Answer (score 2):

Clearly this is impossible in general, as explained by @mixedmath. However, it's quite reasonable to convert 16 bit values that 'fit' into 8 bits, eg 1, -34, 127, etc.

The way to do this may be less than obvious if by 'sign and magnitude' you mean 2's complement ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement)). For example:

- 1 (decimal) = `0001` (16 bit hex) = `01` (8 bit hex)
- 127 = `008F` = `8F`
- -1 = `FFFF` = `FF`
- -128 = `FF80` = `80` (This one always surprises me...)

So the conversion method is easy - simply truncate to the bits you need. Such useful properties of 2's complement are why it is used.

Comment: eh your 127 is wrong it should be `0x7f`